# Accessing a parent's component from inside a nested child's component without rendering child's HTML in parent

Tags: angular

I am trying to access the my parents component variables and methods by doing the following but getting an error message saying:

```
error_handler.js:57 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'getSelectedRow' of undefined
```

I am trying to accomplish this by doing the following:

Parent Component:

```
get self(): SearchComponent{
        return this;
    }
```

Method trying to be accessed from child:

```
getSelectedRow():string {

        if(this.ssn != null){
            return this.ssn;
        }

        return "";

    }
```

Parent's HTML:

```
<user-form [setUserSsn]="self"></user-form>
```

Childs component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'userForm.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userForm.css']

})
export class UserFormComponent {

    private _parentComponent: SearchComponent;

    @Input()
    setUserSsn(parent: SearchComponent){
        this._parentComponent = parent;
    }

    ssn = this._parentComponent.getSelectedRow();
}
```

-----------Update 1--------------------

I have tried a new approach but now I am getting the error:

```
Cannot read property 'getSsnFromSelectedRow' of undefined
```

methods in parent component:

```
setClickedRow(user:User) {

        let ssn = user.ssn;

        this.setSsnForUsersForm(ssn);

        console.log("SSN: "+user.ssn);
    }

    setSsnForUsersForm(ssn:string){
        this.ssnForUsersForm = ssn;
    }

    getSsnFromSelectedRow():string{
        return this.ssnForUsersForm;
    }
```

call in child component

```
ssn = this._parentComponent.getSsnFromSelectedRow();
```

------------------Update 2--------------------------

I guess I need a `@Directive` but I do not think I am using it correctly.

child component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'userForm.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userForm.css']

})
@Directive({selector: '[userSsn]'})
export class UserFormComponent {


}
```

parent.html

```
<tr saSmartMenu *ngFor='let data of user' (click)="setClickedRow(data)">
                    <td><a routerLink="/userManagement/maintainUsers/userForm">{{data.ssn}}</a></td>
                    <td><a routerLink="/userManagement/maintainUsers/userForm">{{data.userId}} </a></td>
                    <td><a routerLink="/userManagement/maintainUsers/userForm">{{data.lastName}}</a></td>
                    <td><a routerLink="/userManagement/maintainUsers/userForm">{{data.office}} </a></td>
                    <td><a routerLink="/userManagement/maintainUsers/userForm">{{data.role}} </a></td>
                    <span userSsn="data.ssn"></span>
                </tr>
```

Now when the user selects a row the child component with know the ssn of the row selected. However it is not working still.

--------------------Update 3---------------

Error:

```
Can't bind to 'parent' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
            </table>
        </div>
        <div userForm [ERROR ->][parent]="self"></div>
    </div>
</div
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'userForm.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userForm.css']

})
@Directive({selector: '[userForm]'})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit  {

    @Input('parent') _parentComponent: SearchComponent;

    private ssn: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ssn = this._parentComponent.getSsnFromSelectedRow();
    }

}
```

parent html

```
<div userForm [parent]="self"></div>
```

Comment: Your parent component is undefined bc u set it before it is passed through to your child. Wrap the setter in the ngOnInit function.. though this whole passing the parent thing is generally bad

Comment: If you want the parent do something triggered by the child, then define an event (using @Output()) in the child and then catch the event in the template of the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tam5 is right. The problem is that you are trying to read an object before is assigned.

`ssn = this._parentComponent.getSelectedRow(); // at this point your setUserSsn hasn't being called yet.`

One possible approach is to implement ngOnInit like this, although there are better approaches https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html :

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// other imports here

export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

    private _parentComponent: SearchComponent;
    private ssn: string;

    @Input()
    setUserSsn(parent: SearchComponent){
        this._parentComponent = parent;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.ssn = this._parentComponent.getSelectedRow();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to render the user form HTML in the parent then the most suitable approach will be a directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// other imports here

@Directive({
  selector: '[userForm]'
})
export class UserFormDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input('parent') _parentComponent: SearchComponent;

  private ssn: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ssn = this._parentComponent.getSelectedRow();
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:
`<div userForm [parent]="self"></div>`

Comment: This does get rid of the error but I do NOT want the HTML to render in the parent at all.

Comment: I don't understand what your original question has to do with what you are saying now. If you define a component in your Parent's HTML: <user-form [setUserSsn]="self"></user-form> then userForm.html will render in Parent's HTML. I'm really confused now.

Comment: There is a variable in parent that I want to pass to my child without rendering HTML that is the end goal.

Comment: You need a directive then not a component

Comment: You need to add the directive to the module declarations https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136577/discussion-between-drew1208-and-artemisian).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass just the selectedRow via @input(), I think sending the hole component isn't good for performace.

Something like that:

Parent's HTML:

```
<user-form [ssn]="ssn"></user-form>
```

Childs component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: 'userForm.html',
    styleUrls: ['./userForm.css']

})
export class UserFormComponent {
    // starts as an empty string to avoid missing parameters issues
    @Input() ssn: string = ''; 

}
```

Comment: I do not was the HTML from the child's component to render in the parents. Your above method does exactly that. Thank you for your efforts. Once a row is clicked in a `*ngFor` there is a `routerLink=` and the child needs to know the `ssn`