# Issue with using a component in two places, move to higher directory

Tags: angular

I ran into this issue so what I did was make a parentModule and imported the other two modules into that and exported the components like so

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SmartadminModule,
        SearchRoutingModule,
        UsersFormModule,
        SearchModule
    ],
    declarations: [UserFormComponent, SearchComponent], //these two were clashing

    providers: [],

    exports: [UserFormComponent, SearchComponent]
})
export class ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule {

}
```

My other two modules that just import the parent module:

```
   @NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SmartadminModule,
        SearchRoutingModule,
        ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule
    ],
    declarations: [SearchComponent],

    providers: [SearchService],

    exports: [SearchComponent]
})
export class SearchModule {

}
```

next

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SearchRoutingModule,
        ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule,
    ],
    declarations: [UserFormComponent],

    providers: [UserFormService],

    exports: [UserFormComponent]
})
export class UsersFormModule {

}
```

error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'UsersFormModule'
Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'UsersFormModule'
```

I did this because I need to import `UserFormComponent` into `SearchModule` but it was complaining it was being used in more than one place.

Comment: A component should **only be declared ONCE**. Your `UserFormComponent` is declared both in `SearchModule` and `UsersFormModule`. You need to declare + export it in ModuleA then import ModuleA in ModuleB.

Comment: I edited my post because I did remove `UserFormComponent` from SearchModule` but it needs to use it. I made a directive in `usersFormCompoment` and I am using it in the `search.html` which is part of the `SearchComponent`. So I imported it and got the clash, therefore I made a `ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule` and exported `exports: [UserFormComponent, SearchComponent]` from it. I then imported `ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule` into `UserFormComponent` and `SearchModule`.
 Even though I removed `UserFormComponent` from `SearchModule`. I am getting the same error what am I missing here.

Comment: Can you describe the goal you're trying to reach? Which component(s) would you like to use in which module(s)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444679/accessing-a-parents-component-from-inside-a-nested-childs-component-without-re/42445005?noredirect=1#comment72035983_42445005 I been at this for days and this post explains everything.

Comment: So, conceptually you have a parent and a child component and you'd like to call one of the parent's methods from the child? If yes that sounds a bit hackish. Could you instead describe what you're trying to do *functionally*, not *technically*? (maybe you need a different approach altogether)

Comment: I have have several rows made by a `*ngFor` loop in my parent, when a certain row is clicked, I want to send a value in that row to the child, in this case a `ssn` so it can use it in its services. When that row is click is is also routed to the child's html page. I do not want to render the child's HTML in the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136623/discussion-between-drew1208-and-angularfrance).

Comment: Hey Drew. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the below code, which is more than enough

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SmartadminModule,
        SearchRoutingModule,
        UsersFormModule,
        SearchModule
    ],
    declarations: [], //these two were clashing

    providers: [],

    exports: [UserFormComponent, SearchComponent]
})
export class ParentMaintainUsersSearchModule {

}
```

Note :

1. UserFormComponent should be in the exports of UsersFormModule
2. SearchComponent should be in the exports of SearchModule
3. When you are importing a module, then all the components that are under exports of that module is also present in your module as well.
4. If your SearchComponent is used across your SearchModule, then only you need the SearchComponent in the declarations part of your module.

**[Live Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/qI8magBrdlgKCpkYlvpn?p=preview)**